# How to install/use audio-common on ros2 humble

Tags: ros2, ros-humble, audio-common, digital-audio

I am trying to use audio-common to capture audio on ros2 humble. I am new to ros, below are few methods I tried with out much success.

** Try 1: **
I tried to install using cmd "sudo apt-get install ros-humble-audio-common" but got error "E: Unable to locate package ros-humble-audio-common".

Question :  Is there any way to install audio-common for ros2 with out having to download code. ?

** Try 2 : **

I downloaded audio-common code from "https://github.com/ros-drivers/audio_common/tree/ros2" and tried to compile package by running "colcon build --symlink-install" . I am seeing issues while compiling audio_capture and sound_play. Following is snap shot of error

```
Starting >>> audio_common_msgs
Finished <<< audio_common_msgs [5.86s]                     
Starting >>> audio_capture
Starting >>> audio_play                      
Starting >>> sound_play                                                      
--- stderr: audio_capture                                                                                          
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:603 (message):
  A required package was not found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:825 (_pkg_check_modules_internal)
  CMakeLists.txt:17 (pkg_check_modules)
```

Question: What all packages I have to install to make sure sound_play is compiled?

** Try 3 : **

After I removed sound_play and installed  some gstreamer related packages i am able to compile successful. But not able to run.

Question: what are the commands to run audio-capture?

Comment: Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange! The following link may help: https://github.com/ros-drivers/audio_common/issues/227

Comment: There seem to be three questions in this one post. Please ask one question per post.